# How to create a form to save 1:n relations in ember.js

Tags: forms, ember.js, relation

I have an 1:n relation. For example one **group** has n **persons**. How do I have to create a form for the entity person with a selectbox to add it to a group? I have tried something like the following view:

```
{{! Create Person}}
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='model.text'}}
{{view Ember.Select 
  valueBinding='model.group'
  optionValuePath='content.id'
  optionLabelPath='content.name'
  contentBinding='App.Group.FIXTURES'
  prompt='Please Select'}}
```

How do I have to modify **contentBinding** that it make sense? I'm using ember.js 1.0.0-RC4.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `selectionBinding` instead of `valueBinding`

Assuming that `person` is available in the current template:

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding='App.Group.FIXTURES'
       optionValuePath="content"
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       selectionBinding="person.group"}}
```

Comment: I Could try it. But how can I bind/fetch the collection of groups? I do not want to use FIXTURES (by the it is not an array of DS.Model objects). The model in my example is a person.

Comment: `contentBinding` can be any javascript object. You can construct it in your controller.